# Jenkins build to run a script when git commit

Tags: bash, git, shell, jenkins

i had a requirement in my office like users modify the files in gitlab. Now my need is to create a jenkins build which will transfer the files to remote server. Can some one please help me on this like to run shell script or how do i proceed. Please help

Answer (score 0):

A quick google will show a couple of answers. There is [Publish over SSH plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Publish+Over+SSH+Plugin) which will transfer files via scp. Separately - there are how to guides that can be found via google.

Comment: Thanks for replying back. i have searched so many links but no luck. Could you please suggest me any link. Our intention is when git is commited with new files those new files will replace in the remote server, these all should be done by prior to Jenkins job. Thanks.